# Prove that $P^{(n)}(x) = a_{n}n!$ if $P(x) = a_{n}\cdot x^{n} + a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{0}$

Tags: calculus

Let $P(x) = a_{n}\cdot x^{n} + a_{n-1}\cdot x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{0}$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. How can we prove that its $n$th derivative is:$$P^{(n)}(x) = a_{n}n!$$

Comment: What about using induction?

Comment: Tried but it is not that trivial :/

Comment: Ok, posted an answer. Please, tell me whether you need further guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

From [here](http://ww.mathportal.org/formulas/derivatives/higher_order_derivatives.php) observe that $$\frac{dx^m}{d^nx}=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}x^{m-n}$$ ([Proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Nth_Derivative_of_Mth_Power#Proof))

$$\text{ So, }\frac{dx^m}{d^nx}=0 \text{ if }0\le m<n\text { and } \frac{dx^n}{d^nx}=\frac{n!}{(n-n)!}x^{n-n}=n!$$

Comment: Yeah I did noticed. But from observation to formal proof there is a pretty big gap.

Comment: @Gerry, could you please elaborate the 'gap' ?

Comment: Thanks for the formal proof @lab bhattacharjee!

Comment: @Gerry, My pleasure. I think the induction on $\frac{dx^m}{d^nx}$ is much clearer than the induction on the Polynomial.

Comment: Yeah you are right! I think this is why I got confused at the beginning :/

Answer (score 3):

By induction: you have $(a_1 x+a_0)' = a_1\cdot 1!$. Thus, the claim holds for $n = 1$. Assume now that the claim holds for $n-1$ and let us show that it implies the claim for $n$.

Let 
$$
  P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k
$$
be any polynomial of the degree $n$, then
$$
  P_n'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot a_{k}x^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k x^k =: P_{n-1}(x)
$$
is a polynomial of the degree $n-1$ with the main term $b_{n-1} = na_{n}$. We know that
$$
  P^{(n)}_n = P^{(n-1)}_{n-1} = (n-1)!b_{n-1} = n! a_n
$$

Comment: How do you know that $P^{(n-1)}_{n-1} = (n-1)!b_{n-1}$? This is what you want to prove isn't it?

Comment: @Gerry: well, that's the whole point of the induction. I should have been more explicit about that, though. Just edited - see 2nd and 3rd sentences of the answer.

Comment: Ok I see. The part that confused me at the beginning was that $P_{n}^{'}(x) = P_{n-1}(x)$ because when you differentiate the original polynomial the result is not the same $(P)$ polynomial but another, say $S_{n-1}(x)$ right?

Comment: @Gerry: of course, I meant $P_n$ and $P_{n-1}$ to bedifferent polynomials (see my definition $...=:P_{n-1}$).

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot Ilya! I think I have to approve @lab bhattacharjee's answer 'cause it was a bit faster. I did upvoted you though!

Comment: @Gerry: thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let you polynomial be $$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$

Note that for any polynomial $q$ of degree $m<n$, we have that $$q^{(m)}\equiv 0$$ (i.e. it is the zero polynomial)

Moreover, note that $$p(x)=a_nx^n+q(x)$$ where $\operatorname{deg}(q)\leq n-1$. Then $$p^{(n)}(x)=a_n(x^n)^{(n)}+0=a_n(x^n)^{(n)}$$

So, you can prove by induction two things now

$1.$ If $q$ is a polynomial with degree $m<n$, $q^{(n)}=0$.

$2.$ If $f(x)=x^n$ then $f^{(n)}=n!$

and you'll be done.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is linear and lower monomials vanish so it suffices to prove $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n x^n = n!$, we prove a slightly stronger statement by induction:

**Theorem** $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k x^n = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} x^{n-k}$.
*proof:* $k=0$ is trivial, suppose it's true for $k$ we show it for $k+1$ by differentating RHS once $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} x^{n-k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!}x^{n-k-1}.$$